# textbox.io editor tool box missing in angularjs ui bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

We are using textboxio editor in our domain. I have integrated textboxio. It's working fine in chrome safari and IE10. But In firefox the toolbar not getting displayed. FYI we are using this inside angular ui bootstap modal. It showing perfectly in the form with out modal. But we need to open it inside the modal
Please help us to fix this problem

Please find plunker link:
[plunker textbox editor link](http://plnkr.co/edit/kFLtVYaLBvrHHdid4qJw?p=preview)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="textboxio.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Textboxio with angularjs ui bootstrap modal</h2>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myModal">
 </button>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" style="height:300px">
            Add some text here
            <textarea id="editorTextArea" name="description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                    data-dismiss="modal">Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Submit changes
            </button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = textboxio.replace('#editorTextArea');
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can change script like this

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      var editor = textboxio.replace('#editorTextArea');
 });  
</script>
```